# Time skipping in Jquery Datetime picker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Using the jQuery datetimepicker, I've noticed that the time options are not displaying correctly. For example, after 15:55, the next available time should be 16:00, but it's showing 16:36 instead. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and knows how to resolve it?

[image]

```
$el.datetimepicker({
                minView: 2,
                timepickerScrollbar: true,
                datepicker: false,
                timepicker: true,
                onChangeDateTime: function(date) {
                    var dt = Utils.getTimeString(date); 
                    $el.find('.input_time').val(dt);
                    $el.find('.time').val(dt);
                }
            });
```